# Does Text-Mask library of React work with Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jsx, text-mask

I have a React project, using an input mask library called [Text-mask](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask).

I want to use the masked phone number value to update the react state value via **Redux**.

But whenever I try to use setClientPhone action, masked input only accepts one letter and then seems broken.

Here is my code.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { setClientPhone } from '../../redux/tab/tab.actions';

import MaskedInput from 'react-text-mask';

const MyComponent = (props) => {
    const {clientPhone, setClientPhone} = props;

    const handleChangePhone = e => {
        setClientPhone(e.target.value);
    }

    const TextMaskCustom = (props) => {
        const { inputRef, ...other } = props;
        return (
            <MaskedInput
               {...other}
               ref={ref => {
                   inputRef(ref ? ref.inputElement : null);
               }}
               mask={['(', /[1-9]/, /\d/, /\d/, ')', ' ', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, ' ', /\d/, /\d/, ' ', /\d/, /\d/]}
               placeholderChar={'\u2000'}
               showMask
            />
        );
    }

    return (
        <Input
            value={clientPhone}
            onChange={handleChangePhone}
            id="clientPhone"
            inputComponent={TextMaskCustom}
        />
    );
}


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    setClientPhone: comp => dispatch(setClientPhone(comp)),
})

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    clientPhone: state.comp.clientPhone,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent);
```

Is there a way to make this work?

*Thanks in advance*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested components definition are a bad idea because are redefined on each render, therefore a new is mounted each render. Define your `TextMaskCustom` component outside of `MyComponent`:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { setClientPhone } from '../../redux/tab/tab.actions';

import MaskedInput from 'react-text-mask';

const TextMaskCustom = (props) => {
        const { inputRef, ...other } = props;
        return (
            <MaskedInput
               {...other}
               ref={ref => {
                   inputRef(ref ? ref.inputElement : null);
               }}
               mask={['(', /[1-9]/, /\d/, /\d/, ')', ' ', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, ' ', /\d/, /\d/, ' ', /\d/, /\d/]}
               placeholderChar={'\u2000'}
               showMask
            />
        );
 }

const MyComponent = (props) => {
    const {clientPhone, setClientPhone} = props;

    const handleChangePhone = e => {
        setClientPhone(e.target.value);
    }

    return (
        <Input
            value={clientPhone}
            onChange={handleChangePhone}
            id="clientPhone"
            inputComponent={TextMaskCustom}
        />
    );
}


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    setClientPhone: comp => dispatch(setClientPhone(comp)),
})

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    clientPhone: state.tab.clientPhone,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent);
```